# Azure workbook filtering based on a selection/click in a chart

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, azure-monitor-workbooks

I would like to filter the data and show the raw/aggregated data in a table/grid when a selection is being done in a Bar Chart in Azure Workbook visualizations.

I have a bar graph as below. When I select on the "purple" line denoting Avg CPU to be very high, I would want a grid/table showing the CPU aggregated on x based on the query. How can this be achieved in Azure workbooks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  see [the azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-interactive) or the [github docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Interactivity.md) for full details but in general:

1. in the advanced settings for the visualization, choose the "when items are selected export parameters" option, and fill that out.
   (note in both docs it calls out that in grids you can export any column in the grid, but in charts, you have different options for x, y, series, etc)

   that will create a parameter with a value when something becomes selected
2. use that parameter downstream, in query text, or in conditional visibility to hide and show other steps

Comment: Do you happen to have any documentation on what the series json will look like?  I am using this technique, but when I attempt to do things like `| extend MyColumn = {myParam}` I'm struggling with the syntax and am unable to unpack the JSON values in order to apply the filters in my queries.  I'm using a pie chart and can see that it's bringing back the `series` but just getting back the error `'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'MyValue'`

Comment: if you add a text step in the workbook right after the grid/etc, you can use it to effectively print out the parameter value in a code block to see how it would be formatted in the query.  if you're exporting all values instead of a specific column, its a standard json object, with a field name and value for each column.  to use it in the query, you'd generally need quotes around it so it becomes a string, then you'd use `parse_json("{param}")` or `todynamic("{param}")` to get values out of it.